# Use of volume backing file size use in devstack?

Tags: cloud, openstack

I am trying to set up openstack on a single machine using devstack scripts. In configuration for cinder this parameter is given `VOLUME_BACKING_FILE_SIZE`. I am not able to understand what is the use of this parameter as we are giving name of volume group and any cinder volumes can be created in that volume group.

Answer (score 0):

In default configuration Cinder use iSCSI+LVM as storage backend.

LVM allows to create Logical Volumes belonging to a Volume Group, these Logical Volumes are actually created and correspond to the Volumes you create in Cinder.

Devstack automatically creates a Volume Group with a loopback device as Physical Volume.
A loopback device is a fake device that actually refers to a file.
VOLUME_BACKING_FILE_SIZE sets the size of this file.

So if you set this size to 10GB, you will be able to create Volumes for a total size of 10GB (i.e. 10 Volumes 1GB each one or 1 volume of 10GB).

Comment: so if i manually create a `Volume Group` and give this to devstack then there is no need to give `VOLUME_BACKING_FILE_SIZE` and devstack will start using my volume group instead of creating a loopback device.